# onAnimation complete display data of Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts

So currently the data is being showed only for the 1st bar i.e-"Listening".
So I want to display the same for the remaining bars!!

[image: Bar Chart]

I am currently using `onAnimation()` function, I just dont know how to pass multiple values in datasets?
Please help me fix this issue!!

Code I have used:

```
$scope.barChartOptions = {
    tooltipEvents: [],
    showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function() {
        this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].bars, true);
    },
};
```